# Elm: String.toFloat doesn't work with comma only with point - what to do?

Tags: elm

I'm very new to elm and i want to do a simple mileage counter app.

If i get `"1.2"` (POINT) form input - `String.toFloat` returns in the OK branch with 1.2 as a number.

But if i get `"1,2"` (COMMA) form input, then `String.toFloat` returns in the Err branch with `"You can't have words, only numbers!"`

This pretty much works like a real time validator.
[image]

The code:

```
TypingInInput val ->
        case String.toFloat val of
            Ok success ->
                { model | inputValue = val, errorMessage = Nothing }

            Err err ->
                { model | inputValue = val, errorMessage = Just "You can't have words, or spaces, only numbers!" } 
   .
```

**Question:** So how can i force `String.toFloat` of "1,2" to give me 1.2 **the number**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the source for `toFloat` is hardcoded to only [respect a dot as decimal separator](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/4.0.5/src/Native/String.js#L262). You can replace the comma with a dot in the string prior to passing it to `toFloat` as a workaround.

[`String.Extra.replace`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/string-extra/1.1.0/String-Extra#replace) can be used for the simple string replacement.

Comment: yes @Chad Gilbert. Thanks this looks way pretty! I replaced the case statement like this: 
`case String.toFloat (String.Extra.replace "," "." val) of` but i run into this errors : `I cannot find module String.Extra` or if i import only String exposing (..) i get: 

`Cannot find variable 'String.Extra.replace` ,  The qualifier `String.Extra` is not in scope`.

I don't know how to solve this. How did you do it?

Comment: Run this from the command line: `elm package install elm-community/string-extra`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chad Gilbert !  I forgot to do the install. Everything works fine now:)

Comment: I guess you could use `String.map` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of [String.toFloat](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/String#toFloat) only supports a dot as a separator.

You should replace commas first before parsing the `Float`

Please see the example:

```elm
import Html exposing (text)
import String
import Regex


main =
  "1,2"
    |> Regex.replace Regex.All (Regex.regex ",") (\_ -> ".")
    |> String.toFloat
    |> toString
    |> text -- 1.2
```

In JavaScript [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) doesn't support comma separator either.